# Responsive Image with Pointers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using  map image on a responsive HTML page. The challenge is to place markers (with links) that remain on the same place on any view port.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you place markers using map API or by your own as a new layer?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour : Yes.. I am using a map.jpg and creating small dots with colored <div> and putting above on a new layer using higher z-index.

Comment: I suggest positioning dots in a '<div>' in your personal monitor width. When User loads the page, get the client width by javaScript and use Css Zoom factor to resize your defined <div> relative to the current page width. I have no Idea how to handle the draggable and zoomable map but my suggestion works for a static (non-draggable and non-zoomable) map. For a dynamic map, using the map API would solve all.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery to point a marker.Here is a code, give you API key and give user lat=""and log="", placeId:"".

Click This site to create API KEY=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div id="map" style="height:260px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(Here is your API key) &libraries=places&callback=initMap">
    </script>
<script>
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 9.992656, lng: 76.290536},
          zoom: 18
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails({
          placeId: 'ChIJLWFBCEENCDsRuBtYV6pjFh4'
        }, function(place, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
              infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                place.formatted_address + '</div>');
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          } 
        });

      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I know with JS API this could be achieved - but here the scenario is different. I am using a map.jpg and creating small dots with colored <div> and putting above on a new layer using higher z-index